# Is there a closed form solution to calculate Fugit for stock options?

Tags: greeks, american-options

I am trying to find a quick and dirty way to estimate fugit for a basket of American options real time. Is there a quick way to provide a proxy? I know one can do binomial tree or monte carlos simulation, but that would just take too long to run for a large universe of options.

Thank you!

Comment: I posed a similar question about American calls embedded in bonds https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/51284 never found anything faster than brute search

Comment: @Dimitri Vulis Thanks, been searching for an answer for a while too here...